# If no errors are showing in the Chrome Javascript Console does that mean the bug in my site isn't Javascript related?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to solve a rather complicated issue with a button in my site that when clicked twice consecutively is not doing what it's supposed to.

I'm not great with JS and new to browser Javascript consoles so I wanted some clarification.

If there are no errors showing in Chrome Javascript Console does that mean that my issue is not JS related?

Hopefully this is a simple yes or no answer?

Comment: We'll need to see some code to help you.
As a short answer though, if you have no error in your console, it means that you have no javascript error. So your button is doing what it's told to.

Comment: No; it just means that your Javascript code didn't throw any errors.  The console does not magically tell you whether your code does what you think it does.

Comment: No, could still be JS related. Impossible to say without code samples.

Comment: Ok so I'll ask a separate question thats specific to my button and share here. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: if the console shows an error, you know there's potentially a JS-related issue, but the console not showing an error does not imply there is no JS-related issue, only that a certain class of JS issues is not present.

Comment: This is more specific to my problem, or at least as specific as I can get it. Any suggestions to get me in the right direction would be appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927201/why-would-clicking-a-button-trigger-more-than-twice-break-my-quick-view-modal

Comment: the link above doesn't work. I have the same issue and can't figure out what's going on. Have you been able to solve this issue?